# Is this sequence bounded in $W_0^{1, p}(\Omega)$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, exponential-function, sobolev-spaces

Let $p>1, \Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be an open bounded domain. Moreover, let $(u_n)_n$ be a sequence in $W_0^{1, p}(\Omega)$ such that
$$a\ge \|u_n\|_{W_0^{1, p}} +\int_{\Omega} h(x),$$
where $a\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and $h$ is a continuous function such that
$$h(x)\ge e^{\alpha x^2}- c_1$$
with $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and $c_1$ is a positive constant.

My question is: in these assumptions, we can say that $\|u_n\|_{W_0^{1, p}}$ is bounded?

About me the answer is yes, since it is (I think):
$$a +c_1 {\rm meas}(\Omega)\ge \|u_n\|_{W_0^{1, p}} +\int_{\Omega}e^{\alpha x^2} dx \ge \|u_n\|_{W_0^{1, p}}. $$

Could someone please tell me if my reasoning holds true or not?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: $\Omega$ is bounded, then $e^{ax^2}$ is a bounded function on $\Omega$, there is no problem with the boundedness claim

Comment: @daw do you mean there is no problem with the boundedness of $\|u_n\|_{W_0^{1, p}}$?

Answer (score 1):

Following your solution, you can arguee by this way:

$$ \| u_n\|_{W^{1,p}_0} \leq a - \int_{\Omega} h(x)dx \leq a  + \int_{\Omega}( c_1 -e^{\alpha x^2})dx$$

and arguing similarly with your answer, you get the thesys.

Comment: So it is bounded in $W_0^{1, p}(\Omega)$, isn't it?

Comment: You just have to arguee about the last integral, I think that’s just to bound it

Comment: The problem is exactly to understand if $-\int_{\Omega} e^{\alpha x^2} dx$ is bounded or not.

Comment: Try to think about the monotonicity of the function in a bounded domain, I'ts just an idea!